# Java bridge'ed error

Tags: java, php, fastcgi

I'm trying to move a JaveBridge'ed project to a new server. Its running PHP w Java throught sun-java6. I don't know how to read java error output and was hoping one of you could  point me in a direction to figured what to do on the server to make this app happy.

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught [[o:Exception]:"java.lang.Exception: CreateInstance failed: new com.elance.proposal.html2image.client.MainBridge. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.elance.proposal.html2image.client.MainBridge VM: 1.6.0_06@http://java.sun.com/" at:
#-29 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
#-28 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
#-27 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
#-26 java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
#-25 java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
#-24 php.java.bridge.Util.classForName(Util.java:1518)
#-23 php.java.bridge.JavaBridge.CreateObject(JavaBridge.java:445)
#-22 php.java.bridge.Request.handleRequest(Request.java:458)
#-21 php.java.bridge.Request.handleOneRequest(Request.java:510)
#-20 php.java.servlet.PhpJavaServlet.handleLocalConnection(PhpJavaServlet.java:202)
#-19 php.java.servlet.PhpJavaServlet.handlePut(PhpJavaServlet.java:250)
#-18 php.java.servlet.PhpJavaServle in http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc on line 195
```

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library or class file that defines `com.elance.proposal.html2image.client.MainBridge` was not found.  Check classpath settings.