# Using Java Within PHP - Class Not Found

Tags: java, php, tomcat

I'm using Tomcat and PHP5 with JavaBridge. I have bridged PHP and Java so I can screencap web pages within PHP. This was working on another server but after moving to a new server I can not get it working, so I'm reaching for straws here.

```
require_once("http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc");
java_autoload("/web/sites/madfrog/domain.com/cron/bin/html2image.jar");
$JavaHTML2Image = new Java("com.elance.proposal.html2image.client.MainBridge");
```

It should have loaded all of the project html2image.jar when the script _autoloaded it, however when you create the new Java object I get the error

```
Class Not Found: Fatal error: Uncaught [[o:Exception]:"java.lang.Exception: CreateInstance failed: new com.elance.proposal.html2image.client.MainBridge. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.elance.proposal.html2image.client.MainBridge
```

I asked the guys over in Java and they said I needed to put the jar file in the lib so Java could find it, so I dumped it into Tomcat's webapps folder an into `/usr/share/java`. But that did nothing. With that said the PHP has a direct reference to it, so it should be loaded.

I'm at a lost after two days. any help is appreciated!

Comment: Looks like a classpath issue: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758916/java-bridgeed-error][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758916/java-bridgeed-error

Comment: Yeah, that's me from yesterday ;p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Tomcat do you use?

For Tomcat 6 or Tomcat 7 put the jar either in `${tomcat.home}/lib` or in `${tomcat.home}/webapps/${your.war}/lib`
While `tomcat.home` is your tomcat installation directory. And `your.war` is the name of your war file.

Comment: Im on Tomcat version 6.0.33. I can just symbolic link it into them folders right?

Comment: Sure, you can use a symbolic link. Just make sure you do it correctly. The best test will be doing something like "ls ${tomcat.home}/webapps/${your.war}/lib/yourjar.jar" and see it there. The "jar" suffix is extremely important.

Comment: Thanks man, I linked it up into ${tomcat.home}/lib and it looks to be working.